# Элементы <marquee> располагаются вертикально в САФАРИ

Tags: css, ios, safari

На сайте есть бегущая строка , абсолютно везде элементы бегут в строчку, но в SAFARI, либо в еще некоторых браузерах, в частности в адаптиве (при отображении на телефоне) - Список элементов "едет" стройным столбиком - В этом и есть проблема.

Код строки:

```
<marquee style="height: 17px">
              <div class="lenta-rbk">
<div style="direction: ltr; text-align: left ! important">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="moduletable">
            <tbody><tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>
            <ul class="newsfeed">
                            <li>
                                    <a href="http://www.rbc.ru/business/11/07/2017/5964d46d9a79474268a5e0ef" target="_blank">
                    Суд за турбины: как Siemens пытается избежать санкций за поставки в Крым</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="http://www.rbc.ru/business/11/07/2017/5965166b9a7947e3600c9b29" target="_blank">
                    «Ростех» получит долю в крупнейшем золотодобытчике России</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="http://www.rbc.ru/rbcfreenews/596513899a7947deccc6e130" target="_blank">
                    Семья основателя «Черкизово» выкупит 21% компании у Prosperity Capital</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="http://www.rbc.ru/business/11/07/2017/5964ace49a79472faf913d81" target="_blank">
                    Производители меди в России решили увеличить добычу в надежде на дефицит</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="http://www.rbc.ru/rbcfreenews/5964f1209a79474b17576819" target="_blank">
                    Экс-менеджеры «Башнефти» оспорили решение суда о премиях в компании</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="http://www.rbc.ru/rbcfreenews/5964e80b9a794754b5cda4be" target="_blank">
                    ЦБ выявил признаки инсайдерской торговли акциями «Нижнекамскнефтехима»</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="http://www.rbc.ru/business/11/07/2017/5964eab39a79477b95435daa" target="_blank">
                    ФСБ пришла с обысками в офис компании «Т Плюс»</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="http://www.rbc.ru/business/11/07/2017/5964c8819a794733879aaeae" target="_blank">
                    Siemens подал в суд из-за поставки его турбин в Крым</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="http://www.rbc.ru/rbcfreenews/5964a66a9a7947d3a7376eae" target="_blank">
                    Германия назвала поставку турбин в Крым «ударом по инвестициям» в Россию</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="http://www.rbc.ru/rbcfreenews/5964a5f59a7947cf2989eaf3" target="_blank">
                    ФАС прекратит принимать жалобы по тендерам на капремонт от физлиц</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</div>
</div>
          </marquee>
```

Код стилей:

```
#banner_g2 marquee{position:absolute;bottom:15px;height:17px !important}
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо задать отображение списка с одну строчку:

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Чтобы работало и в Хроме, и в Сафари, надо сделать так:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

См. сниппет.

```css
#banner_g2 {
  width: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  height: 18px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner_g2">
  <marquee>
    <ul class="newsfeed">
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.rbc.ru/business/11/07/2017/5964d46d9a79474268a5e0ef" target="_blank">
                    Суд за турбины: как Siemens пытается избежать санкций за поставки в Крым</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.rbc.ru/business/11/07/2017/5965166b9a7947e3600c9b29" target="_blank">
                    «Ростех» получит долю в крупнейшем золотодобытчике России</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.rbc.ru/rbcfreenews/596513899a7947deccc6e130" target="_blank">
                    Семья основателя «Черкизово» выкупит 21% компании у Prosperity Capital</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.rbc.ru/business/11/07/2017/5964ace49a79472faf913d81" target="_blank">
                    Производители меди в России решили увеличить добычу в надежде на дефицит</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.rbc.ru/rbcfreenews/5964f1209a79474b17576819" target="_blank">
                    Экс-менеджеры «Башнефти» оспорили решение суда о премиях в компании</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.rbc.ru/rbcfreenews/5964e80b9a794754b5cda4be" target="_blank">
                    ЦБ выявил признаки инсайдерской торговли акциями «Нижнекамскнефтехима»</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.rbc.ru/business/11/07/2017/5964eab39a79477b95435daa" target="_blank">
                    ФСБ пришла с обысками в офис компании «Т Плюс»</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.rbc.ru/business/11/07/2017/5964c8819a794733879aaeae" target="_blank">
                    Siemens подал в суд из-за поставки его турбин в Крым</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.rbc.ru/rbcfreenews/5964a66a9a7947d3a7376eae" target="_blank">
                    Германия назвала поставку турбин в Крым «ударом по инвестициям» в Россию</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.rbc.ru/rbcfreenews/5964a5f59a7947cf2989eaf3" target="_blank">
                    ФАС прекратит принимать жалобы по тендерам на капремонт от физлиц</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </marquee>
</div>
```

Comment: В том то и дело, что у них стоит inline-block, я видимо не все стили показал вам

Comment: А согласно правилам сообщества, вы должны были создать Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Я поставил ширину в моем сниппете - 320px. И все равно работает. У вас ошибка в стилях где-то вне примера.

Comment: Прошу прощения, ссылки давать нельзя, показал, как мог (

Comment: Сделал я и для этого дебильного уродства под названием Сафари. Работает.